# Sudo not available in docker image despite being installed in base image

Tags: docker

I can't access Sudo from my container, despite it looking like the base image has it installed.

```
nistmni@ca5af2f4aace:~$ sudo echo x
bash: sudo: command not found

nistmni@ca5af2f4aace:~$ /bin/sudo
bash: /bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

My Dockerfile is simple:

```
FROM nistmni/minc-toolkit

RUN mkdir ~/execute

COPY . ~/execute/

CMD /bin/bash
```

The Dockerfile for nistmni/minc-toolkit is:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

# install basic system packages
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         sudo \
         build-essential g++ gfortran bc \
         bison flex \
         libx11-dev x11proto-core-dev \
         libxi6 libxi-dev \
         libxmu6 libxmu-dev libxmu-headers \
         libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev \
         libjpeg-dev \
         libssl-dev ccache libapt-inst2.0 git lsb-release \
         curl ca-certificates unzip && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# add user to build all tools
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash nistmni && \
    echo "nistmni ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/nistmni && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/nistmni

ENV PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:$PATH

# add new cmake
RUN mkdir src && \
    cd src && \
    curl -L --output cmake-3.14.5.tar.gz https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.14.5/cmake-3.14.5.tar.gz  && \
    tar zxf cmake-3.14.5.tar.gz && \
    cd cmake-3.14.5 && \
    ./configure --prefix=/usr --no-qt-gui && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    cd ../../ && \
    rm -rf src

USER nistmni
ENV HOME /home/nistmni
WORKDIR /home/nistmni
```

Is this:

1. Some subtlety of base images I don't understand
2. Sudo is getting removed somewhere I'm not seeing
3. Not actually the Dockerfile being used to create the image

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value for PATH when you're logged in? Can you see sudo in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Why do you believe that is the Dockerfile used to build the image? The `nistmi/minc-toolkit` image(s) appear to be built from the Dockerfiles published at https://github.com/vfonov/minc-toolkit-containers, none of which mention `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks.  When inheriting from an image like this, is it possible to get back to root in my dockerfile, or should I copy their dockerfile steps at the start of mine?

Comment: You pretty much never need `sudo` in Docker: you can always use the Dockerfile `USER` directive or the `docker run` or `docker exec` `-u` option to pick a different user.

Comment: What command exactly can I use to go back to root in my dockerfile when the FROM has left me as a different user?

Comment: USER root is the way